# How to obtain the analytic representation of the given infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

This series is given in Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics chapter 3 in an example explaining seperation of variables.

> $$V(x,y) = \frac{4V_0}{\pi} \sum_{n=1,3,5\ldots} \frac{1}{n}e^{-n\pi x/a}\sin(n\pi y/a)$$
>   $$V(x,y) = \frac{2V_0}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\pi y/a)}{\sinh(\pi x/a)} \right)$$

I don't have any idea how to get the analytic representation of the series. I tried replacing $n$ by $
-n$ to get hyperbolic sine but it also introduces summation over negative odd integers and I don't think they can be added over. Also, it will form hyperbolic sine in the numerator rather than the denominator. How to proceed?

Comment: Replacing $n$ by $-n$ doesn’t make the sine turn into a hyperbolic sine.

Comment: A sum over negative integers is perfectly valid, but I don't think it helps here.

Comment: In the old days one spend a lot more time poring over math tables and just knew which section to go look in...

Comment: Put $n=2k-1$, use $\sin\,x =\frac {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} {2i}$ and you will end up with a series of the type $\sum \frac {r^{k}} {2k-1}$ with $|r| <1$. Can you handle this series?

Comment: Yeah, it's solved. Thanks.